# Angular Directives : How to change "template as function" to "templateUrl"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJS. I am trying to modify one of the directives

Current code:

```
template:   function(tElement, tAttrs){
      return  "<div ..........>"+
               "<div>"
```

I want to change like:

```
templateUrl: 'some.html'
```

Note: I have copied the HTML part code from the template and created file called 'some.html' but it's not working.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please, explain what 'it's not working' means. What is the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, you need to return an object, like so:

```
return {
        templateUrl: 'some.html'
    }
```

As long as your file path is correct then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you return a valid json object in the return of the directive
2. Make sure you have only one root element of your html content - that is 
   template like this -

   ```
   <div>...</div>
   <div>...</div>
   ```

is not allowed you need to have one root element like this -

```
<div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

3. To have scope values need to be set to the html content use link and make it available.

Below is a complete simple example of a directive and its html

```
   myTestApp.directive('directive', function(configuration) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'myContactTemplate.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.config = configuration;
        }
      };
    });
```

HTML

```
<div>{{config.name}}<br>Version: {{config.age}}</div>
```